# Computer vision system toolbox MATLAB

Tags: computer-vision, video-capture, matlab, matlab-cvst

I have found the [image processing toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/image/) for matlab, but all demos included in that toolbox expect the input to be avi videos. Does this toolbox work with webcams and/or simple images? If yes, could someone show me how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For live video, or still images from a camera your tool of choice is the [image acquisition toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/imaq/). This, combined with the image processing toolbox you found, makes matlab quite the powerful video processing tool.

[This small sample](http://www.cs.ait.ac.th/~mdailey/matlab/#images) shows how to read image files into matlab matrices.

Answer (score 1):

I know this probably isn't very helpful, but Mathworks likes to push Simulink as their tool of choice for streaming applications, including video processing.

http://www.mathworks.com/products/computer-vision/index.html

Comment: The Computer Vision System Toolbox is for MATLAB as well as for Simulink.